# fgets reads 4 charachters when buffer is 5

Tags: c

When using the input `hello world` to this program it outputs `hell` which is less than 5 why does this happen

```
void grab_user_input()
{
    char user_input[10];
    if ( fgets(user_input, 5 , stdin ) !=  NULL )
    {
        printf("%s\n",user_input);
    }
}

int main()
{

    grab_user_input();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last byte is the null byte `\0`.

Read the [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) manual for more info. Here's an excerpt:

> `char *fgets( char *restrict str, int count, FILE *restrict stream );`
>
> Reads at most `count - 1` characters from the given file stream and stores them in the character array pointed to by `str`. Parsing stops if a newline character is found, in which case `str` will contain that newline character, or if end-of-file occurs. If bytes are read and no errors occur, writes a null character at the position immediately after the last character written to `str`.